# Google .NET Client Youtube v3 error

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I get this following error when trying to upload a video to my youtube channel:

**System.ArgumentException: Precondition failed.: !string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.RefreshToken)**
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.d__0.MoveNext() in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default_3\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 356

**The Code:**

```
   class Program
    {
        private const string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "685082793570-acspgovnpo2dfmcb5fsqdu5e0q7pdmn1@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        private const string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = @"97b6020dc5777485250124e25b788e4b8ed3324e-privatekey.p12";

        static YouTubeService BuildService()
        {
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret",X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            var provider = new AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, certificate)
            {
                ServiceAccountId = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
                Scope = YouTubeService.Scopes.YoutubeUpload.GetStringValue()            };
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(provider, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

            return new YouTubeService((new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                            {
                                Authenticator = auth,
                                ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
                            }));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var youtube = BuildService();

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "Video title";
            video.Snippet.Description = "Video description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";  // "Video privacy (public, private, or unlisted)";
            var filePath = "52224a59-2029-43fd-806b-efc434256c25.mp4";
            var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

            var videosInsertRequest = youtube.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            var upload = videosInsertRequest.Upload();
            Console.WriteLine(upload.BytesSent);
            Console.WriteLine(upload.Status);
            Console.WriteLine(upload.Exception);
}
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?
I'm using version 1.5.0.28972 of Google.Apis
DotNetOpenAuth version: 4.0.0.11165

Comment: I think the problem is due to not signing up properly on youtube.{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.header",
    "reason": "youtubeSignupRequired",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized"
 }
}

Comment: We just released a new Auth library which should make your life easier. Read more in https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Account_(available_only_on_.NET_framework_4), and download our Google.Apis.Auth NuGet package. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In the new release (1.6.0-beta) which was announced several weeks ago, (Read more in our announcements blog [here](http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/2013/10/announcing-release-of-160-beta-new.html)) we presented a new Auth library which supports different Windows platforms and different flows (including service account).

Read more in our OAuth2 page and specifically [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Account_%28available_only_on_.NET_framework_4%29). The new library doesn't include a dependency in DNOA any more, so it should be very easy to use and debug.

Hope it is helpful, keep me updated.